# What are the proper steps to calibrate my mouse before playing FPS games?

Tags: mouse, first-person-shooter

I always have problem to properly calibrate my mouse when playing FPS games (Combat Arms). Sometimes it is too slow or too fast, sometime my movements are not smooth enough. My mouse is Razer Copperhead.

What are the proper steps to calibrate my mouse before playing FPS games?

Is it better to set it fast in the Configurator and slow in the game or in reverse?

What is better DPI higher or not for FPS games?

Comment: Are you sure this is not performance related?

Comment: *What are the proper steps to calibrate my mouse for playing Combat Arms?* 'calibrating' mice isn't a thing, that game just sucks. And it needs a tag.

Answer (score 2):

> "I always have problem to properly calibrate my mouse when playing FPS games (Combat Arms)."

I know this answer is very late; but I've played quite a bit of Combat Arms over the years and I believe it's critical to OP's (former) issues.

Combat Arms in 2011 was using an engine similar to what is now available as "Combat Arms: Classic" (this is not the same as the one available on Steam called "Combat Arms:Reloaded"; which doesn't have these issues).  In the old engine, there are a couple things to note about mouse movement.

Combat Arms had forced mouse smoothing (I can't find the reference for this anymore, it was said by a developer on Nexon forums when they were working on CA:Reloaded).  The best way to help avoid major effects from that was to put a cap on the FPS that you could maintain constantly.

> "My mouse is Razer Copperhead."

Razer Copperhead, like many gaming mice, has a polling rate up to 1000 Hz.  Combat Arms doesn't like that.  The aim will zig zag and not follow straight paths if the polling rate is above 125 Hz.  Most gaming mice have settings to limit the polling rate in their software.

**TL:DR**  The Combat Arms: Classic (or Combat Arms in 2011) engine does not work well for calibrating mice in general.  The game has **forced mouse smoothing** so using **fixed FPS** is suggested.  It also requires a **polling rate of 125 Hz or below** to allow the mouse to move in straight lines.

**Update:** If (for some reason) you do still want to play Combat Arms Classic with a 1000Hz mouse, I have found the workaround for that as well.

In your Combat Arms Classic folder there are two .exe's for the game. Engine and Engine2. Engine2 is actually a "beta" build that has been included with classic for awhile.

The Engine2.exe actually works to run the game, (and removes forced mouse smoothing) as long as the game is up to date (which means you need to run the normal launcher to update the game).

You'll want to make a shortcut for Engine2.exe. Then right-click on the shortcut and go to properties. Where it says Target, add -windowtitle to the end of the target. It should look something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CombatArms Classic\Engine2.exe" -windowtitle
```

This shortcut will launch the game with the build which removes the forced mouse smoothing.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult answer which are the best DPI settings for an FPS. There any too many different variables like the mouse device self (resolution, weight, etc.), the material/brand of your mouse pad or the surface if you haven't one, your hand posture and the force you apply, etc.

Then it depends also how the game implements the mouse input, and even sometimes depends on the class you are using. For example in *Team Fortress 2* I use two different settings if I play Sniper or I use Heavy instead.

In the end, if it can help, I suggest you to define as many different profiles as your mouse control software can support (3, 5 or more) and set constant DPI interval between them.

For example I set my Logitech profiles to 800-1000-1200-1400-1600 DPI and then in-game I can easily change between them using the dedicated buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the sensitivity and DPI to be on a one to one ratio on the pad and on screen is bogus for FPS gaming. You don't want to move your mouse 20 inches or more to cover one screen width turn in game, about 90 degrees. It would be very precise movement but useless in FPS, where you do 90 degree turns frequently just to walk around the map. Let alone if you want to be watchful or evade enemy attack.

You want to [turn off Windows, mouse driver and in game mouse acceleration](http://wiki.sourceruns.org/wiki/Disabling_Mouse_Acceleration). This can be done from the mouse control panel entry and many games also have their own setting for this as well.

Then you have to figure out the mouse driver and in game mouse sensitivity settings so as to produce the actual DPI you have selected. The sensitivity settings are sort of like mouse acceleration in that this calculation alters your actual physical DPI the mouse delivers. I am simplifying this for convenience sake. But generally if you set sensitivity very high or low it ends up either extrapolating DPI, which produces skipping, or in interpolates needlessly making same DPI feel very slow.

Comment: "The sensitivity settings are sort of like mouse acceleration in that this calculation alters your actual physical DPI the mouse delivers." +1. So, don't ever touch the in-game slider, and make your mouse not suck in the first place. Also, don't play games with bad code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old of a thread but for any future reference it's best to measure the distance your mouse PHYSICALLY moves as you move across the screen.  Then in game move the "sensitivity" until it's the same.